# Why can't I pass general JSX to a wrapped component in react?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am using React15 with typescript. Below is my code:

```
const WrappedComponent = (WrappedComponent: React.ComponentType<any>) => (<WrappedComponent className="my-class" />);

WrappedComponent(<div />);
```

I defined a `WrappedComponent` method which accepts any react component. Then I call that method passed a `<div />` element. But I got below error:

```
Argument of type 'Element' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentType<any>'.
  Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'StatelessComponent<any>'.
    Type 'Element' provides no match for the signature '(props: any, context?: any): ReactElement<any> | null'.
```

It reports a type error about `Element` and `ComponentType`. I wonder how I should convert the Element to a react component method. Isn't a JSX element a React component?

Another question is about how to define a general component properties to replace `<any>` in WrappedComponent?

Answer (score 0):

JSX elements aren't components. JSX decompiles to `React.createElement` calls, not components:

https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html

In React a component has to be a class that extends `Component` with a render method, or a function that returns JSX.

If you want to pass in and render arbitrary JSX in a component then just use `children`. Or if you need something more complex then try a render prop:

```
const Wrapper = ({ render }) => <div>{render()}</div>

<Wrapper render={() => <div/>} />
```

Comment: Is there a way to reuse the component rather than reuse the render method? It is pretty easy to do in javascript but quite hard to do so in typescript.

Comment: Isn't stateless component a Component in typescript?